# how to filter IP address based and group them into different lists based on the first octet in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a list of IP addrress, original = ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.4.1", "1.3.45.67", "1.3.67.89"]. This list has 1000s of IP address.
I want to create groups which matches the first two octets. 
Group1 = ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.4.1"]
Group2 = ["1.3.45.67", "1.3.67.89"]
How can I achieve this in nodejs?

**The following code works, but would like to know much simpler way to achieve the same.**

```
let initArray=['172.25.17.42','172.21.17.5','172.22.45.2','172.22.66.5','172.25.5.2','172.21.8.27','172.25.13.30','172.21.14.13','172.21.17.5','172.05.17.42','172.06.17.5','172.07.45.2','172.06.66.5','172.05.5.2','172.07.8.27','172.05.13.30','172.06.14.13','172.07.17.5','172.11.17.42','172.12.17.5','172.11.45.2','172.12.66.5','172.33.5.2','172.40.8.27','172.33.13.30','172.40.14.13','172.50.17.5'];
initArray.sort();

var resArray = [];
initArray.forEach(function (eachIP) {
 let ocTets = eachIP.split('.');
let twoOctets = ocTets[0]+'.'+ocTets[1];
resArray.push(twoOctets);
})
const counts = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < resArray.length; i++) {
var num = resArray[i];//num = 171.21
counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;//counts[171.21  = 1]
}

let sum = 0;
var newMap = new Map(Object.entries(counts));
var resMap = new Map();
console.log(newMap);
let keyarray = [];
let j=0;

newMap.forEach((value, key, thisMap) => {
    sum+=value;
    if(sum<=5){
        keyarray.push(key);
    }
    else
    {
        keyarray.push(key);
        console.log('keyarray:'+keyarray);
        let keyStr = keyarray.toString();
        resMap.set(keyStr, sum);
        while (keyarray.length) { keyarray.pop(); }
        sum = 0;
    }
})

console.log(resMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

ipv4 IP addresses are just 32-bit numbers.  While it may be convenient for a human to view an IP as a four-octet string, it's generally easier to write IP logic using numbers.  For example, in your code you sort the IPs, but the IPs are sorted alphanumerically which probably is not what you want.  One approach, then, is to map all of your IP addresses to numbers and then apply your grouping logic.

Take the IP addresses `172.25.17.42` and `172.25.5.2`.  These respectively map to `0xAC19112A` and `0xAC190502` in hex.  You can see right away that the first two octets match (`0xAC19`).

Given the numeric representations of the IPs, simply shifting each number right by 16 bits gives you the desired grouping.  Alternatively, you can mask off the bits other than the two octets you want (keep in mind that JavaScript numbers are 64-bit).

I would follow this recipe:

1. Convert the IPs to numbers.
2. Shift each number right by 16 bits to get the first two octets.
3. Reduce the list of IPs down to an octet-to-IP map/the format desired format (e.g. octet group to count or whatever).

Here's some code.

```js
const ips = ['172.25.17.42', '172.21.17.5', '172.22.45.2', '172.22.66.5',
  '172.25.5.2', '172.21.8.27', '172.25.13.30', '172.21.14.13', '172.21.17.5',
  '172.05.17.42', '172.06.17.5', '172.07.45.2', '172.06.66.5', '172.05.5.2',
  '172.07.8.27', '172.05.13.30', '172.06.14.13', '172.07.17.5', '172.11.17.42',
  '172.12.17.5', '172.11.45.2', '172.12.66.5', '172.33.5.2', '172.40.8.27',
  '172.33.13.30', '172.40.14.13', '172.50.17.5'];

// Reduce the array of IPs down to a map of first-two-octets to IP.
const octetMap = ips
  .reduce((map, ip) => {
    // The first two octets of the IP as a number.
    const firstTwo = ip2int(ip) >> 16;

    // Alternative approach (JS numbers are 64 bit).
    //const firstTwo = ip2int(ip) & 0x00FF0000;

    // First time seeing firstTwo initialize an array, then add the IP.
    if (!map.has(firstTwo))
      map.set(firstTwo, []);
    map.get(firstTwo).push(ip);

    return map;
  }, new Map());

console.log(octetMap);

// This returns an unsigned 32-bit integer representation of the ip string.
function ip2int(ip) {
  return ip
    .split('.')
    .reduce((num, oct) => (num << 8) + parseInt(oct, 10), 0) >>> 0;
}
```